# Best way to avoid nested ternary with form validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to do form validation using `react-form-hooks`. I've set up the requirements for my form element like this:

```js
<TextField
  label="Email"
  {...register("email", {
    required: true,
    pattern: emailRegex,
    maxLength: 60,
  })}
  error={errors.email}
  helperText={
    errors.email?.type === "required"
      ? "Email is required"
      : errors.email?.type === "pattern"
      ? "Invalid email"
      : errors.email?.type === "maxlength"
      ? "Email too long"
      : ""
  }
/>
```

It works, but it's far from readable. I use ternary quite often for choosing between text options for react component parameters and I think that previously it made sense as I always had 2 options so far, but here I have 3 and for some other I might even have 4.

I couldn't find examples with best practices for this scenario of filling helper text (or like of it) with different strings based on error. Here are 2 ways I've came up with to solve this:

1. Using `function` and `switch`:

```js
const getEmailHelperText = (errors) => {
  switch (errors.email?.type) {
    case 'required':
      return 'Email is required.'
    case 'pattern':
      return 'Invalid email'
    case 'maxlength':
      return 'Email too long'
    default:
      return ''
  }
}

/// ...

<TextField
  label="Email"
  {...register("email", {
    required: true,
    pattern: emailRegex,
    maxLength: 60,
  })}
  error={errors.email}
  helperText={getEmailHelperText(errors)}
/>
```

2. Using `useState()` and `useEffect()`

```js
const [emailHelperText, setEmailHelperText] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  switch (errors.email?.type) {
    case 'required':
      setEmailHelperText('Email is required.')
      break
    case 'pattern':
      setEmailHelperText('Invalid email')
      break
    case 'maxlength':
      setEmailHelperText('Email too long')
      break
    default:
      setEmailHelperText('')
  }
}, [errors]);

// ...

<TextField
  label="Email"
  {...register("email", {
    required: true,
    pattern: emailRegex,
    maxLength: 60,
  })}
  error={errors.email}
  helperText={emailHelperText}
/>
```

Is there a better, "right" way to do it? If not - which one of those two makes more sense? Is more efficient?

Comment: Your approach with the function is the one I would recommend. Don't use state and or useEffect if you do not necessarily need to. This will cause unwanted rerendering.

Comment: @JannisMorgenstern Won't this `useEffect()` only run when `errors` are updated? Which is only when it should run and cause re-render?

Comment: Yes the `useEffect` will only run when `errors` changes. But the `setEmailHelperText()` will set state and rerender the component which is not needed if you can accomplish the same result using a regular function. In general you should use state only if your value does not exclusivly depend on `props` or other `state`. Also I think using a function is a lot cleaner and more readable so why not go with that approach?

Comment: @JannisMorgenstern I guess there is no reason not to. Thank you for clearing that up for me.